# How to tweak WHERE clause to select all records when passing NULL as a parameter in SQL statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

If @reasonID = 1 I need to select only policies that have reasonID = 211

If @reasonID = 2  I need to select only policies that have reasonID <> 211

If @reasonID = NULL  I need to select all policies including `NULL`

In the below example it works for @reasonID = 1 and @reasonID = 2.

But how can I tweak WHERE clause to select all rows when @reasonID = `NULL` ?

```
      declare @TempTable table (PolicyNumber varchar(50), reasonID int)
        insert into @TempTable values ('Pol1', 5),
                                      ('Pol2', NULL),
                                      ('Pol3', 211),
                                      ('Pol4', 8),
                                      ('Pol5', 211),
                                      ('Pol6', NULL)

   --input @reasonID parameter     
  declare @reasonID int = 2
  select PolicyNumber,reasonID
  from @TempTable
  where 
    (case when reasonID = 211 then 1 else 2 end = @reasonID) --works fine
    OR (@reasonID = NULL)          --does not work
```

Comment: @reasonID IS NULL, do not use `=` with NULL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You use `IS NULL` not `= NULL`.

Your last line should be:

```
OR (@reasonID IS NULL)
```

And, if you ever want to do the reverse, the syntax is `IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thanks. I'll accept the answer but I reposted question with more details. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55054756/how-to-tweak-where-clause-to-select-all-records-without-premium-0-when-passing